# Backup for Mac? Alternatives to Apple Time Capsule?

Tags: data-storage, backup, macbook

I used to backup my MacBook to the Apple Time Capsule. It saved me several times in the past ~5 years. Since Apple is not manufacturing this device anymore, I wonder what is the current most effective tactic available to make sure my MacBook is backed up every single day?

Comment: Do you mean without remembering to connect a drive specifically? Otherwise, any old USB drive will do. Do you have another always-available Mac, or a NAS?

Comment: I'm traveling, so can't use wire connections to hotel network. It would be great if I could just plug the backup device to electricity socket and my MacBook would use it as is, without the requirement to connect to the same wifi network or wire. Are there anything like this?

Comment: I'm not really au fait with on-the-road solutions, I've never needed them, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I travel and use a vpn to home, then [Borg](https://medium.com/macoclock/backing-up-with-borg-on-mac-os-x-fcac50df5188) to backup efficiently to my server at home.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.arqbackup.com/ is a nice tool that can allow you to schedule backups to various locations and do all sorts of other stuff. One nice thing about it is that it is a gui so it's very easy to delve into what you're working on.

This could be you backing up to cloud storage or even to an external disk connected to your system.